# Как мне вызвать с моей программы файловый менеджер чтобы выбрать файл?

Tags: java, android

Моя программа должна работать с парой форматов (в будущем будет до 10). 
Мне необходимо что бы пользователь мог выбрать файл и моя уже программа этот файл как-то обработала. Это файлы субтитров и текста все различного.

Comment: проверяйте какой extension выбран у файла и подсовывайте соответствующий интент

Comment: Я о том что сначала нужно ж выбрать файл..а как его выбрать ??? (Ну и получить ссылку на него

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если не хотите зависеть от сторонних файл-менеджеров берите [aFileChooser](https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser) вставляйте проект как либу и вперед. Вызов элементарный:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Create the ACTION_GET_CONTENT Intent
    Intent getContentIntent = FileUtils.createGetContentIntent();

    Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(getContentIntent, "Select a file");
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CHOOSER);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CHOOSER:   
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                final Uri uri = data.getData();

                // Get the File path from the Uri
                String path = FileUtils.getPath(this, uri);

                // Alternatively, use FileUtils.getFile(Context, Uri)
                if (path != null && FileUtils.isLocal(path)) {
                    File file = new File(path);
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Метод `getContentIntent()` легко кастомизируется под нужный тип файла, заданием mime типа:

```
public static Intent createGetContentIntent() {
        // Implicitly allow the user to select a particular kind of data
        final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("*/*"); //задаем mime тип
        // Only return URIs that can be opened with ContentResolver
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        return intent;
    }
```

**Update**

Проект слегка морально устарел, но тем не менее вполне работоспособен. Кое-какие `action` можно уже и другие использовать, есть проблемы с `FileUriExposedException`, но если руки не сильно кривые то все можно приспособить

Comment: У меня прям большой задачи нет, всего выбор файлов с определенными форматами и их использование

Comment: Спасибо, это наверняка поможет.

Comment: Можно ли кастомизироать под несколько форматов?

Comment: Рескажите об Exception который может возникнуть по подробнее

Comment: Он возникает если засунуть `Uri` типа `file://` для передачи во внешний `Intent` - [подробнее здесь](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileUriExposedException.html)

Comment: Столкнулся с проблемы если выбрать определенный item в Navigation Drawer то ссылка на файл равна null

Comment: одна тема - один вопрос, сформулируйте и выставьте как положено